# Return the last value of an INT in a new cell

Tags: sql, presto

I am trying to assign specific rows in a sheet to an agent, based on the last value of the Row_Number column. If the Row_Number ends in 0-4 then I want for the cell beside it to state John. If the Row_Number ends in 5-9 then I want the cell beside it to state Sam.

This is the result that I would like to see;

```
| Row_Number  | Agent_name  |
|-------------|-------------|
|      1      |     John    |
|      2      |     John    |
|      3      |     John    |
|      4      |     John    |
|      5      |     Sam     |
|      6      |     Sam     |
|      7      |     Sam     | 
|      8      |     Sam     |
```

Here is what I have so far;

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id DESC) AS Row_number,
      CASE WHEN RIGHT("row_number",1) BETWEEN 0 AND 4 THEN John
           WHEN RIGHT("row_number",1) BETWEEN 5 AND 9 Then Sam
      END AS AGENT_NAME
FROM table
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER ASC
```

It seems that Presto might not support the `RIGHT` function which is where I am getting stuck. Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `substr()` :

```
SELECT Row_number, (CASE WHEN substr(reverse(Row_number), 1, 1) BETWEEN 0 AND 4 
                         THEN "John"
                         WHEN substr(reverse(Row_number), 1, 1) BETWEEN 5 AND 9 
                         THEN "Sam"
                    END) AS AGENT_NAME
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id DESC) AS Row_number, *
      FROM table
     ) t;
```